# VueJs: How to pass a 'computed function' value from child component to the parent component using $emit(optionalPayload) and $on?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to VueJs and I am doubtful about passing the optional payload
Could anyone please tell me how to pass the value returned by a computed function in the child component to the parent component using the optional payload.

I want to implement a separate independent search component which returns the search results to all other components. The computed function looks like this:

```
get computedSports () {
    if (!this.searchModel || this.searchModel.length === 0)
       return this.sports
    else
       return this.fuseSearch.search(this.searchModel)
}
```

This is how I am trying to pass the value returned by computed function to its parent component in the child template:

```
@input="$bus.$emit('computed-sports', computedSports)"
```

In the parent component, this is how I am trying to access the value of the child's computed function:
    `v-on:computed-sports=""`
I am not quite sure how to access the value here. Could anyone help me out in this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to a `v-on` should be a method or inline function that takes the payload as an argument. For example

```
v-on:computed-sports="handleComputedSports"
```

and your method might be defined

```
handleComputedSports(theValue) {
  console.log("The value is", theValue);
}
```

There's an example in [this section of the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events). Your emit is fine. The fact that the value comes from a computed makes no difference to anything.